# update with query of multiple fields from various tables

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have the following tables:

book_tbl:

```
book_instance_id | book_type_id | library_instance_id | location_id | book_index
1                | 70000        | 2                   | 0           | 1
2                | 70000        | 2                   | 0           | 2
3                | 70000        | 2                   | 0           | 3
4                | 70000        | 3                   | 0           | 1
5                | 70000        | 3                   | 0           | 2
6                | 70000        | 3                   | 0           | 3
7                | 70000        | 4                   | 1           | 1
8                | 70000        | 4                   | 1           | 2
9                | 70000        | 4                   | 1           | 3
```

and library_tbl:

```
library_instance_id | library_type_id | location_id
2                   | 1000            | 0
3                   | 1001            | 0
4                   | 1000            | 1
```

I would like to update the field `book_type_id` in `book_tbl` only for the first element (index) in `library_type_id` 1000

To retrieve this information I used sqlite query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( ( SELECT *
                  FROM library_tbl
                  WHERE library_type_id=1000 ) t1
                join book_tbl t2 on t1.location_id=t2.location_id
                                AND t1.library_instance_id=t2.library_instance_id
                                AND book_index=1 )
```

How could I use the query above with UPDATE query to update rows 1 and 7:

```
UPDATE book_tbl SET book_type_id=15000 WHERE ????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EXISTS with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to check whether the corresponding library row exists:

```
UPDATE book_tbl
SET book_type_id = 15000
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM library_tbl
              WHERE library_type_id = 1000
                AND location_id         = book_tbl.location_id
                AND library_instance_id = book_tbl.library_instance_id)
  AND book_index = 1;
```